# Adding a CMS to an existing Magento shop

Tags: wordpress, drupal, magento, cms

I am working on a project for 3 niche stores built on magento (using magento's multi-store function)  that each get roughly 50k unique visitors a day.  The sites don't currently have a blog or forum or any social networking aspects.

Would like to add a cms to each site that can be centrally run and would like it to take over the front end content from Magento.  Also would like it to maintain an online blog/publication of sorts with videos, articles, and the like with privileges to edit the content given to a dozen or so people with different privileges.  Want to add a forum to each site that is fairly robust and to possibly add some social networking aspects down the road, so extandability and available plugins/mods in each cms is important.

Other than shared login between the forums,blog/publication and store, would like to be able to integrate some content from the forums and blog/publication into the store as well.

After researching this a bit, I am inclined towards Drupal, but I haven't found any modules to integrate it with Magento.  Also, since the blog content will be done by about a dozen nontechnical people, I want something that is very easy to work with.  Lastly, since the site gets a good amount of traffic, speed and security are very important.

What CMS would you recommend integrating in this context?  Deciding between Drupal, Wordpress and ModX.  Also Plone as well.

Thanks.

Comment: belongs on webmasters.stackexchange - there are commercial and free modules available for blogs, forums and CMS enhancement.  If you have a programming question, feel free to rephrase your question.

Comment: this question is not a programming question. Just install wordpress to /blog/  folder on your site and live happily ever after

Comment: have you looked at typogento? http://www.typogento.com/ .

Comment: thanks for the link to typogento, looks interesting.  i'll move this over to stackechange as well.  just as a note, i don't think it is in any way comparable to use basic magento modules that provide some of the functionality provided by a cms like drupal or plone.

Comment: Dont install wordpress on the same server as an eCommerce platform. Wordpress is an insecure web application.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of which platform you choose, **DO NOT** install it on the same server as an eCommerce platform unless you have expert knowledge about virtual hosts and web application security, or are working with a webhosting company that can provide proper segmentation. All the applications you mentioned are subject to major security flaws that could allow an intruder into your server.

Comment: Man this question is old. How did I get here???

Answer (score 1):

This plugin integrates both Magento and WordPress http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magento-wordpress-integration/ hopefully you chose WordPress as it's the most popular CMS out here are some features of the plugin

- Bring out any of the default Magento Blocks in your WordPress theme.
- Bring out any Magento blocks that you have created yourself.
- Bring out any static blocks that you have made in your Magento admin
  area.
- Show Magento products on a WordPress post or page by using the
  shortcode add-on.
- Show products from any category using the widget add-on.

The same developer also made a single sign on plugin integrating the users of Magento and WordPress